# Rebuild dependencies for an activity that gets created only once since it's launch mode is "singleTask"

Tags: android, android-activity, dagger

I have an activity that gets created once as it's launch mode is "singleTask".
The problem is when I logout and login with some other user the dependencies of this activity don't get rebuild and keep using the profile of the older user.

I resolved the problem by rebuilding dependencies in onNewIntent , but I don't think it's a good solution since this activity will be called many times and unnecessarily the dependencies will be rebuilding again and again.

For me it will be ideal if i can rebuild the dependencies of this activity everytime i login and never again in the same life-cycle.

How can we achieve that?

Comment: What do you mean by "rebuild dependencies"? Please explain your problem in more detail.

Comment: Why don't you just call `finish()` on the `Activity` when the user logs out? When the user logs in again the `Activity` will be recreated. If this doesn't make sense please add more explanation to your question. It is not clear what your problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Single you dont want to change the single top property , you can remove the activity from your activity stack , then relaunch it with new dependencies, thereby avoiding on new intent
Although single top is not preferred for such activities

Comment: sorry , my bad , it's not singletop it's singletask